# How to edit & update custom post from frontend in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a "Product" type custom post. I want to edit and update these from frontend. Title, Description, Feature Image, Gallery Image, Price etc. I'm not want to use WP-Admin panel.

Please give me reference, how I can do this and where I start form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use shortcode plugin that can edit layout/content from frontend, but until now wordpress didn't provide function to edit title, Feature Image, Gallery Image, Price from frontend, just from backend(edit-post)